# how can i manipulate style of a html element in functional react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to manipulate style properties of a html element in react.

At first i thought i can create an object

```
let style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "705px",
  left: "0px",
  border: "0px solid red",
  zindex: "3",
};
```

and then tried to manipulate the html element like this;

```
style["left"] ="250px";

<canvas
   ref={ref_yazi}
   style={style}
   width={100}
   height={100}
/>
```

but it gave me an error and i found out that objects are read only in strict mode so i looked around and found some solutions for this but generally all of them are for class based components (using this.state) and i am using functional component with usestate().

So my question is, how can i implement this in a functional component with usestate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your style object (or just some props within it) stateful using `useState` as well. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({
    position: "absolute",
    top: "705px",
    left: "0px",
    border: "0px solid red",
    zIndex: "3"
  });

  const setStyleProp = (prop, value) => {
    setStyle({
      ...style,
      [prop]: value
    })
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={style}>Hello</div>
      <button onClick={() => setStyleProp('left', '250px')}>
        Change left
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

So you can now call `setStyleProp('left', '250px')` to set the style prop you want on your stateful object.

**Edit:** [Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-smoke-3cz14) demonstrating this.

Comment: Thank you, after a few modifications it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

[Externalisez ses styles](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4902061-developpez-une-application-mobile-react-native/4916061-appliquez-des-styles-a-vos-components#/id/r-4966613) may help you. You need to create a function inside your style object which contains all your styles, than call this method in your style's property in reactJS.